# Dynamic Date Range in SSRS or SQL Data Tools builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, sql-server-data-tools

I am making a report that will run on the 1st of every month and on the 16th of every month.

If it is running on the 1st I need the @start_date to be the 16th to the last day of the previous month.

If it is running on the 16th I need @start_date to be the 1st of the month through the 15th of the month.

I can think of a couple ways to do this, but I am curious is SSRS/Report Builder/SQL Data Tools builder has an easy method for setting this up.

My option was to make a SQL query that does what I need then plug that into the Get Balues from a query part of the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the report in the first part of the month then the parameters should be set to the 16th to the end of the previous month; if run in the second part of the month then the parameters should be set to the 1st to the 15th of the current month.

`@start_date` Default Value expression:

```
=IIF(Day(Today) >= 16, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Day(Today), Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 16-Day(Today), Today))))
```

`@end_date` Default Value expression:

```
=IIF(Day(Today) >= 16, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 15-Day(Today), Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Day(Today), Today))))
```

Comment: I think there is a missing `)` on each code block at the very end.  Just FYI but otherwise works like a charm.

Comment: I had a requirement change thrown at me.  So if the day the report is being run is < the 15th.  the `start_date` should be the first of last month and the `end_date` should be the last day of the previous month.  Is that an easy change to make?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I just changed the `16-Day(Today)` to be `1-Day(Today)`